# how can i check the CC and BCC is valid or not?

Tags: java, regex

I need regular expression for CC and BCC in mail. How can I check whether it is valid or not?

Currently I am using this regex for mail:

```
"^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@ [A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"
```

Now, I also need regex for CC and BCC.

I want cc and bcc like this format
`karan dani <karandani@xyz.com>, abc pqr <abc@xyz.com>`

Comment: Doesn't the same work??? All email IDs are the same right?? Whether it's in `to`, `cc` or `bcc`???

Comment: That regex is painfully lacking. There are a lot more valid email characters than the ones you have in there. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part

Comment: The space after `@` doesn't look right to me (although this isn't the problem).

Comment: 'cc' & 'bcc' are also email ids right?? Use the same  regex if it works for the 'to' email id.

Comment: CC and BCC are _still_ email addresses. The rules for them are the same as for the `to` field.

Comment: i want cc and bcc like this format

karan dani <karandani@xyz.com>, abc pqr <abc@xyz.com>

Comment: You can have that format in the "to" field as well. The problem here in the first place is that the regex is not valid. Even if you fix that, your problem is twofold: 1. You only match one email, specifically, no names. 2. You need to make the same regex work for more than one time per line.

Comment: I really must ask why you need this, because there is possibly a much better way to do this than using regex. So why?

Comment: tell me what is the other way to do this..